# Are these two different definitions of simply connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

In Donald Marshall's notes on complex analysis he defines a region, $\Omega$ as simply connected if $S^2 \setminus \pi(\Omega)$ is connected where $\pi$ is the steregraphic projection. This seems to include regions like $\Omega = \{z : \|z \| > 1\}$ since $S^2 \setminus \pi(\Omega)$ is the just lower hemisphere which is connected.

In algebraic topology, a region is simply connected if any two closed curves in $\Omega$ are homotopic. But, thinking of $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$, this would exclude the $\Omega$ above since a loop around the missing hole is not homotopic to a loop that does not go around the missing hole.

Are these definitions meant to be different? In complex analysis, are we allow a homotopy to "go through infinity"? Am I just missing something?

Comment: @freakish yes, I did mean that $\Omega$. I've edited my question, thanks! For your second point, thank you. I see what you are saying now. Since the north pole of $S^2$ will never be included, that helps make the region on $S^2$ not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This seems to include regions like $\Omega = \{z : \|z \| > 1\}$ since $S^2 \setminus \pi(\Omega)$ is the just lower hemisphere which is connected.

Nope. $S^2\setminus\pi(\Omega)$ has two components: one corresponding to the interior of the circle, i.e. $\{z:\lVert z\rVert\leq 1\}$ plus the point at infinity $\infty$ where the stereographic projection is based at. The $\infty$ point is not in the image of $\pi$, and so it will belong to every subset of the form $S^2\backslash\pi(A)$. Its just that in this case it is a component.

These two definitions are indeed equivalent, although probably not easy to show.

Answer (score 1):

For a connected open set $\Omega\subset\Bbb C$, asserting that $\Omega$ is simply connected in the sense that any two closed curves in $\Omega$ are homotopic is equivalent to the assertion that the complement of $\Omega$ on the Riemann sphere is connected. You will find a proof that John B. Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable I*, for instance. Take a look at theorem 2.2 from chapter VIII, where a list of *nine* (!) equivalent conditions is given.